# what is opaque parameter in the init function of linux kernel module

Tags: linux-kernel, kvm

As the title asks, what is opaque parameter in the init function of linux kernel module?

I've seen this in kvm_init function, and failed to see the reference of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Opaque* means that this parameter is deliberately unexplained, because no guarantee is given about its format.

If the parameter were documented, someone would write a program manipulating it, which would fail in curious and interesting ways when some internal design changes.

It is questionable whether this is actually good programming practice.

Comment: Oh, so the name is opaque.